# Calling Select Tag from URL

Tags: html, url, formatting

I have a webpage with a `<select>` tag called `dropDown` with selectable options 'OptionA', 'OptionB' and 'OptionC'.

It is possible for me to link to the webpage and call one of the options from the URL?

For example: `smaple.aspx?dropDown=OptionB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the GET parameter with JavaScript

```js
let params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
let dropDownValue = params.get("dropDown");
```

then change the select value with JavaScript(assume the select element has a `id` called `a-dropdown`)

```js
document.getElementById('a-dropdown').value = dropDownValue;
```